# JS server already running react native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial from here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html. I'm able to boot up my package manager with `react-native start`. But running the application itself always results in a crash.

```
$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to use shared archive.
An error has occurred while processing the shared archive file.
Unable to unmap shared space.
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You already have a react native process running in the background on the same port.

Use `ps -ef | grep react`
and then kill the process using the process id
`kill -9 pid`

and then re execute the command:
`react-native run-android`

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm on Windows. That command doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del] to bring up the Windows Security screen, click Start Task Manager, Find the React Process. Click "End Process " and then try  "react-native run-android"

Comment: Or if you cant do that just restart your computer.

Comment: I don't know the name of the processes or at least can't see it. I tried removing the adb processes that I saw as an attempt, but I'm still getting the same error. I've also restarted my computer several times.

Comment: Have you made sure you have setup you Andriod Dev Environment properly ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: Yeah I did. This isn't my first Android-based project and in fact I had this up and running just earlier today.

Comment: The only thing that worked was completely uninstalling Java on my computer and then re-downloading the JDK.

Comment: Ending the adb.exe task in Task Manager worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all give proper permission to your gradlew, in your root directory run following command

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

> After this make sure you have local.properties file in your android folder with sdk file path like

```
sdk.dir = /home/username/Android/Sdk/
```

Answer (score -1):

### Probable Cause of this error:

***USB debugging not enabled on your device(s)**

### Workaround

Make sure that USB debugging is enabled on your Android device.
Find more about [Enabling USB Debugging on an Android Device](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/android/en/enabling_usb_debugging_on_an_android_device.html)
 Here.

I was facing the same error and was able to resolve it after enabling USB debugging.

Once enabled running the command `adb devices` inside your terminal, you'll see the list of devices with online status.

[Here's the final result for me after trying the above workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ4Da.png)